# What is "detwinning" as a 2D crystallography technique?

Tags: terminology, crystallography, x-ray-diffraction, neutrons

The Phys.org article [Iron selenide revealed as 'garden-variety iron-based superconductor'](https://phys.org/news/2019-05-iron-selenide-revealed-garden-variety-iron-based.html) is quoted below. Normally I would hesitate to quote so much but in this case it all seems germane.

**Question:** What is "detwinning" as a crystallography technique? It seems a bit complicated for 2D crystals, with phrases like "... reasoning that the pressure needed to align the larger sample would also cause the layers of iron selenide to snap into alignment." it sounds like manual re-arrangement at almost the atomic scale.

The article links to [Anisotropic spin fluctuations in detwinned FeSe](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41563-019-0369-5) in Nature Materials. (also in [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.08399) and [Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333260261_Anisotropic_spin_fluctuations_in_detwinned_FeSe))

---

[image]

> Tong Chen, a Rice PhD student "detwinned" iron selenide crystals by gluing them atop much larger crystals of barium iron arsenide. Using a 2014 method developed at Rice, the larger crystals are placed under pressure and detwinned, causing the smaller iron selenide crystals to also snap into alignment. Credit: Jeff Fitlow/Rice University

---

> Physicists refer to this directionally dependent behavior as anisotropy or nematicity, and while structural nematicity is known to occur in iron selenide, Dai said it has been impossible to measure the exact electronic and magnetic order of the material because of a property known as twinning. Twinning occurs when layers of randomly oriented 2-D crystals are stacked. Imagine 100 baseball diamonds stacked one atop the other, with the line between home plate and second base varying randomly for each.

> "Even if there is directionally dependent electronic order in a twinned sample, you cannot measure it because those differences average out and you wind up measuring a net effect of zero," Dai said. "We had to detwin samples of iron selenide to see if there was nematic electronic order."

> Study lead author Tong Chen, a third-year Ph.D. student in Dai's research group, solved the twinning problem by cleverly piggybacking on a 2014 study in which Dai and colleagues applied pressure to detwin crystals of barium iron arsenide. It was impossible to apply the same method to iron selenide because the crystals were 100 times smaller, so Chen glued the smaller crystals atop the larger ones, reasoning that the pressure needed to align the larger sample would also cause the layers of iron selenide to snap into alignment.

> Chen spent weeks creating several samples to test in neutron scattering beams. About 20 to 30 1-millimeter squares of iron selenide had to be aligned and placed atop each crystal of barium iron arsenide. And applying each of the tiny squares was painstaking work that involved a microscope, tweezers and special, hydrogen-free glue that cost almost $1,000 per ounce.

> The work paid off when Chen tested the samples and found the iron selenide was detwinned. Those tests with neutron scattering beams at Oak Ridge National Laboratory, the National Institute of Standards and Technology, the Technical University of Munich and U.K.'s Rutherford-Appleton Laboratory also showed iron selenide's electronic behavior is very similar to that of other iron superconductors.

> 

Comment: there is no `neutron-diffraction` tag, so I've added `x-ray-diffraction` and `neutrons`.

Comment: and so I've asked [Tagging questions on diffraction of things other than X-rays?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4511/16035)

Comment: Detwinning is not a novel technique; it's been around since 1940s. These days it's more often done computationally rather than treating crystals "mechanically".

Comment: @andselisk Thanks, that will be good to know once I understand what it is!

Comment: Well, the first question would be, do you know what a twin in a crystal is?

Comment: @JonCuster not in a 2D crystal I don't. I think an answer will have to at least touch on how twinning arises in 2D crystals.

Comment: @uhoh - if you know what it is in a 3D crystal, the extension (contraction?) to 2D is pretty straightforward and what you would expect. The twin is a line defect in the 2D structure with mirror symmetry between the two sides.

Comment: @JonCuster I am not sure if the paper is talking about that *within the plane*, or normal to it, (i.e. plane-to-plane) in the stacking of the planes.

Comment: @uhoh - good point. Although, if a "2D' crystal is thick enough to have twin planes I'm not sure I'd call it "2D" anymore.

Comment: @JonCuster and If they can be moved around relative to each other just by pushing on them, I'm not sure I'd call it "3D" yet either, thus I've asked this question to find out more about what's actually going on here.

Comment: @uhoh - well, that kind of is how twins in real 3D crystals are eliminated as well - you 'just' have to push one layer one spot over and now the layers all stack up 'properly'.

Comment: Given the lesser number of observables (compared to walking around a 3D crystal, even if it were one of elder Stoe imageplates offering only a $\phi$-scan) discerning merohedral and non-merohedral twinning in 2D crystallography still is as routinely possible by means of x-ray diffraction as for 3D samples?

Answer (score 4):

TL,DR: Detwinning splits twins.

A crystal may consist of multiple domains, i.e. areas (2D crystal) or
volumes (3D crystal) sharing the same chemical composition (what atoms and
molecules occur), and crystal phase (think polymorphism as e.g. introduced
for anatase vs rutil).  Per sé, each of these domains can be seen as a small
crystal, i.e. with isotropic and anisotropic properties.  The spatial alignment
of these sub-units can be described relative to the coordinate system of
the large crystal, as well among each other.

In the model of *mosaic crystals*, the crystal consists of small grains;
their orientation (in respect to the coordinate system of the large
crystal) typically varies only a little, and the variation is *random*.
This contrasts to *twins*; here the orientation of the domains *relative
to each other* can be described by symmetry operations like a mirror
plane (leading to *mirror twins*), an axis of rotation (*rotation
twins*), a centre of inversion (*inversion twins*).  That is, you can
describe domains relative to each other and their atomic positions by
a transformation matrix, a *twin law*.  (An important tool solving and
refining a crystallographic models by X-ray diffraction.)  The mere
description of a crystal *as twinned*, however, does not describe (yet)
the number of of individual twin domains in the crystal, nor the ratio
of the volumes concerned:

[image]

(source: [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/science/feldspar/Crystal-structure#ref618147))

***Detwinning*** then is *a procedure to split the domains apart from
each other*.  This can be attempted numerically at an analytical level
(at various stages analyzing diffraction patterns, for example), or
mechanically.  Depending on the case, this can be simple, difficult, or
impossible.  Diffraction intensities of different domains can overlap, or be separate of each other (merohedral / nonmerohedral twinning)**. The
mechanical approach can fail for (a non-exhaustive list):

- sample crystal *overall* is too small to be manipulated
- domains are too small to be easily recognized, e.g. by polarization
  microscopy monitoring manipulation, or/and manipulated
- twin domains can contact each others (easier case), or intersect and
  mutually penetrate each other
- Cutting crystals introduces mechanical stress.  A split along the
  cleavage planes is an approach more gentle and hence less harmful for the
  sample quality.  Yet the application of mechanical stress can introduce
  additional domains, increase mosaicity, or render the fragments too small
  for the X-ray *single crystal* diffraction equipment at disposition.
  (However, diffraction analysis is not constrained to X-rays, (cf. vide
  supra).  Crystals suitable for electron diffraction (not *imaging**)
  can be *considerably* smaller than the ones for in-house X-ray diffraction
  analysis [down to µm scale].)

Finally the discern of 2D/3D crystallography.  Apparently, there is no
generally accepted definition how many µm along $(x,y,z)$ represent the
critical threshold between a film/a surface 2D crystal, and a volumetric
3D one. Probably better defined with the number of translations of the
unit cell along vectors $(a,b,c)$, I guess.

* Gruene, T.; Holstein, J. J.; Clever, G. H.; Keppler, G. Establishing
electron diffraction in chemical crystallography. *Nat Rev Chem* **2021**, *5*,
660–668. https://doi.org/10.1038/s41570-021-00302-4

** Herbst-Irmer, R. Twinning in chemical crystallography – a practical guide. *Zeitschrift für Krist. Cryst. Mater.* **2016**, *231*, 573-581. https://doi.org/10.1515/zkri-2016-1947

Comment: Instead of "separate of each other, or overlap (merohedral / nonmerohedral twinning" I think it should be "overlap, or separate of each other (merohedral / nonmerohedral twinning. Also, I think after detwinning, the crystals are 3D.

Comment: Interesting and helpful, thank you! The fourth sentence of the Nature Materials paper (I added more links to it) begins as follows: "By applying a uniaxial pressure along one-axis of the orthorhombic lattice to detwin the sample..." which is confusing, but I've asked "What is" and not "How does it work" so that will have to be asked separately (along with "What (the heck) is 'uniaxial pressure' in the context of detwinning?") Thanks for the idea of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaicity now I'm going to see if there's a "Difference between polycrystallinity and mosaicity?" question possible.

Comment: update: Thank you for "mosaicity" - now I'm finding all kinds of interesting material to read. This might be exactly what I need to read about in the real world (outside of SE).

Comment: @Karsten Re merohedral/nonmerohedral twinning: I agree, there was an edit.  And with a reference to one or Regine Herbst-Irmer's publications, there now is one of the more accessible introductions to the topic added, too. I equally agree on «if an intentional split a crystal along cleavage planes is possible, and one subsequently can stack fragments on top of each other, it is a 3D crystal»

Comment: @uhoh There has been an edit to the answer about twins/detwinning.  Former member of Sheldrick's group, much of Mrs Herbst-Irmer's work (both journal publications, as well as presentations and tutorials) dealt with the topic. Hence one of the references was added, too.

Comment: @uhoh "Uniaxial pressure" There are these [jacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_(device)) to lift a car (e.g. when replacing a flat tire). Column-like in shape, put orthogonal to the street's surface, there is only one vector to describe the force. Or a cell where the sample is compressed like in a vise.  If the crystal sample however were floating freely in a liquid, the application of pressure *on the liquid* would then exercise force on the crystal, now from all directions (top, bottom, left, right, you name it) from around the sample. Uniaxial in respect to the crystal's axes, too.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look in the morning. Okay, one can take a macroscopic force, divide it by the area of a surface over which it is applied, and call it uniaxial pressure at the surface. Inside that material though, the (what I want to call *actual*) pressure would be isotropic, no? Uniaxial pressure is a concept taught in school and used by jack sales people to sell more jacks, but "actual pressure" is still a scalar, isn't it?

Comment: @uhoh In absence of a surface / phase boundary, is there an internal pressure for a homogeneous sample? Preparing mashed potatoes, for example, I apply *force* in one direction on them ($p = \frac{\vec{F}}{A}$). Yet simultaneously to the compression, there is expansion of potatoes as a conservation of volume below the masher (let's assume they are not a gas, not a foam, nor a sponge and hence, compression is less likely). Based on this, "uniaxial pressure" better should be read as "uniaxial force" - don't you think so, too? And second, isn't a vector like force always uniaxial/unidirectional?

Comment: I think there is only pressure while the mashed potato "fluid" is moving - while it's a dynamical system. Since they are not confined to a volume, in a static situation they will always expand to relieve any internal pressure (except of course the tiny gradient due to gravity). So in the case of mashed potatoes, there is a pressure defined at the masher-potato interface specified by the force per unit area at that point, with the axis being the normal to the interface. After all this, I now understand what they mean; they apply a force.

Comment: I'll try to check tomorrow, but I don't think we can assume that this force does not induce any strain in the other two directions however. I don't know about mashed potatoes, but for this solid material there must be some kind of a [Poisson's ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_ratio)...

Comment: I've added a 2nd bounty to I can award both answers.

Comment: @uhoh The article about Poisson's ratio wasn't anticipated.  Its implications (incl. [orthotropic materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthotropic_material), and [auxetic materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxetics)) provide an additional perspective on many topics, both on macroscopic scale (support structures architecture, construction, mechanical engineering), as well as on microscopic scale (I think piezoelectric crystals were an example).

Answer (score 2):

The work is about the magnetic structure of the material, probed with neutron diffraction. Thus, the twinning disorder is not only in the positions of the atoms but also in the orientation of the nuclear spins.

Wikipedia states in an article on magnetic structure:

> Such ordering can be studied by observing the magnetic susceptibility as a function of temperature and/or the size of the applied magnetic field, but a truly three-dimensional picture of the arrangement of the spins is best obtained by means of neutron diffraction. Neutrons are primarily scattered by the nuclei of the atoms in the structure. At a temperature above the ordering point of the magnetic moments, where the material behaves as a paramagnetic one, neutron diffraction will therefore give a picture of the crystallographic structure only. Below the ordering point, e.g. the Néel temperature of an antiferromagnet or the Curie-point of a ferromagnet the neutrons will also experience scattering from the magnetic moments because they themselves possess spin. The intensities of the Bragg reflections will therefore change. In fact in some cases entirely new Bragg-reflections will occur if the unit cell of the ordering is larger than that of the crystallographic structure. This is a form of superstructure formation. Thus the symmetry of the total structure may well differ from the crystallographic substructure. It needs to be described by one of the 1651 magnetic (Shubnikov) groups rather than one of the non-magnetic space groups.

Here is a conceptual sketch of the expected diffraction image (reciprocal space or Q-space) from a [paper](https://DOI:%2010.1103/PhysRevB.102.054430) on a different material, NaFeAs (with the same senior author):

[image]

The green dots are the signals they are interested in. The red dots are from parts of the crystal where the spins have a different pattern. The uniaxial strain (squeezing in one direction rather than placing in a pressure chamber exerting pressure in all directions) suppresses the signals shown with the red dots, but in this case not completely.

For a general introduction about twinning (merohedral and non-merohedral), see e.g. [this paper](https://journals.iucr.org/d/issues/2003/11/00/ba5036/ba5036.pdf). What the Phys.org article is trying to say is that the 2D order is perfect, but in order to get 3D order, they applied pressure along one crystal axis. You can see this nicely in a perfect crystal of a barium-iron-arsenide crystal that undergoes a twinning transition at low temperature. Here is the description from a [video](https://youtu.be/AHVvVnSMwVk) showing the transition, with a screenshot below:

> Structural "twin" domains forming in a barium-iron-arsenide crystal as it is cooled down to 5 K (- 451 °F). This video, using polarized optical microscopy, shows the formation of these domains, which are caused by a slight change of the positions of the atoms within the crystal.

[image]

As you can see from the titles of the journals where this work is published, this would probably get a better answer from a physicist familiar with solid state methods, magnetic properties and superconductivity.